# awk to search the string and count for total in a one liner

Tags: awk

I have logs like as given sample below, where I'm simply looking for a `SUCCESS` string in the log file and counting the total.

```
$ cat ansible.log
lnx-host01.tin.com | SUCCESS => {"changed": false, "ping": "pong"}
lnx-host02.tin.com | SUCCESS => {"changed": false, "ping": "pong"}
```

This is what the simple straightforward way, but I'm wondering if it can be done with `awk` itself as a one liner without passing to the `wc` command.

```
$ awk '/SUCCESS/{print $0}'  ansible.log | wc -l
66

OR

$ awk '/SUCCESS/' ansible.log| wc -l
66
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here it is:

```
awk 'BEGIN { count=0 } /SUCCESS/ { count++ } END { print count }' ansible.log
```

Of course this would have also worked:

```
grep -c SUCCESS ansible.log
```

Comment: +1 for short `grep` solution (was going to post it but you were faster)

Comment: @ A.B , thnx , how about `awk '/SUCCESS/ {count++} END{print count}' ansible.log`

Comment: Works *almost* fine too. It will print an empty line instead of 0 in case of no match (then count is considered by default an empty string). So if you can garantee there's always at least one `SUCCESS`  then it's good enough. We're not on [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) heh.

Comment: That's fine @A.B  :-) , indeed we are not in Code Golf .

Comment: @krock1516 change `print count` to `print count+0` and you will be fine.

Comment: @krock1516 and you can make it even shorter with `awk 'c+=/SUCCESS/{}END{print c+0}'`

Comment: @mosvy,  thnx it helps